# Android Wear onDataChanged isn't called

Tags: android, wear-os

I downloaded a ready phone app and trying to implement a watchface for my android wear project. The goal is to pass temperature information from phone to the wear device and have it update the watchface.

I have tried:
1. same package name
2. same applicationId
3. same dependencies versions
4. same permissions
5. on my phone side I know for sure that my data is different every time (so the update has to happen)

I also use data items so my data has to get synced.

```
private void syncWatch(String min, String max, int image){
    Log.v("SunshineSyncAdapter", "syncWatch");
    String time =  String.valueOf(new Date().getTime());
    PutDataMapRequest putDataMapRequest = PutDataMapRequest.create("/weather-update");
    putDataMapRequest.getDataMap().putLong("time", new Date().getTime()); // MOST IMPORTANT LINE FOR TIMESTAMP

    putDataMapRequest.getDataMap().putString("min-temp", min + time);
    putDataMapRequest.getDataMap().putString("max-temp", max + time);
    Log.v("SunshineSyncAdapter", min + time + " " + max + time);
    PutDataRequest request = putDataMapRequest.asPutDataRequest();

    if (mGoogleApiClient == null){
        Log.v("SunshineSyncAdapter", "NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO, life is no good");
        return;
    }

    Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem(mGoogleApiClient,request).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DataApi.DataItemResult>() {


        @Override
        public void onResult(DataApi.DataItemResult dataItemResult) {
            if (!dataItemResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                Log.v("MainActivity", "Something went wrong, watch was not notified");
            } else {
                Log.v("MainActivity", "Success, Watch Notified");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I first run my app on the phone make sure it runs correctly and that it updated and sends data items to my wear device. Then I run my wear module and receive nothing because onDataChanged method is never being invoked.

```
 @Override
    public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEvents) {
        Log.v("SunshineWatchFace", "onDataChanged");
        try{
            for(DataEvent dataEvent: dataEvents){
                if(dataEvent.getType() != DataEvent.TYPE_CHANGED){
                    continue;
                }

                DataItem dataItem = dataEvent.getDataItem();
                if(dataItem.getUri().getPath().compareTo("weather_update") == 0){
                    DataMap dataMap = DataMapItem.fromDataItem(dataItem).getDataMap();
                    minTemp = dataMap.getString("min-temp");
                    maxTemp = dataMap.getString("max-temp");
                    weatherImage = dataMap.getInt("weather-image");
                    Log.v("SunshineWatchFace", minTemp);
                    Log.v("SunshineWatchFace", maxTemp);
                }
            }
            dataEvents.release();
            if(!isInAmbientMode()){
               invalidate();
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.v("SunshineWatchFace",e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Would really appreciate any help

[GitHub_Link](https://github.com/JennyCh/udacity_6)

I have spent a lot of time trying to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sent you a pull request on GitHub with corrections. 
Seems like you just forget to connect your google client :)

```
mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

And some additional small changes in your code (some refactoring).

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a BroadcastReceiver in your WatchFace class, and register it under the registerReceiver() method.

Create the BroadcastReceiver first, for example:

```
final BroadcastReceiver mWeatherReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Get the data from the intent here 
            // and set the variables you're going to use in your onDraw method
        }
};
```

Then register the receiver, for example:

```
  private void registerReceiver() {

         //This is where you have the default watch face receiver 
        // Register your new weather receiver
        IntentFilter weatherFilter = new IntentFilter("ACTION_WEATHER_CHANGED");
        SunshineWatchFace.this.registerReceiver(mWeatherReceiver, weatherFilter );
    }
```

Finally, on the onDataChanged of you WatchListenerService, send the data via Intent to the BroadcastReceiver. For example:

```
        @Override
            public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEvents) {

           // Check the data type
                    if (event.getType() == DataEvent.TYPE_CHANGED) {
                    // Get the data map
                    dataMap = DataMapItem.fromDataItem(event.getDataItem()).getDataMap();
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "DataMap received on watch: " + dataMap);

                    // Get the data map items
                    String sunshine_temperature_high = dataMap.getString("sunshine_temperature_high");
                    String sunshine_temperature_low = dataMap.getString("sunshine_temperature_low");

                    // Create the intent
                    Intent send_weather = new Intent("ACTION_WEATHER_CHANGED");
                    send_weather.putExtra("sunshine_temperature_high", sunshine_temperature_high);
                    send_weather.putExtra("sunshine_temperature_low", sunshine_temperature_low);
                    // Broadcast it
                    sendBroadcast(send_weather);

                }
                else if (event.getType() == DataEvent.TYPE_DELETED) {
                    // DataItem deleted
                }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add your CanvasWatchFaceService as listener to data changed events? In onConnected make sure you call:

```
Wearable.DataApi.addListener(mGoogleApiClient, this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your should always check if:

1. Your mobile is connected to the wear
2. The package names are the same
3. You are using the same Google Play service version on both apps
4. You are signing both mobile and wear apps using the same keystore

I got stuck on GoUbiquitous for 10 days until I figure out the last one :-\